# Restrict Fileupload size in SmarGWT component UploadItem

Tags: smartgwt

is it possible to restrict the file size in smartGWT component UploadItem in client side itself rather than doing in server side?

```
UploadItem fileItem= new UploadItem(IMAGE);
```

note: i know we can do this validation on server side but want to avoid the api call

Comment: I think you can't do it client side in plain SmartGWT, but I also don't think you need to make an api call to restrict this server side (is this what you meant by "avoid the api call"?). Just declare the size in your data source descriptor.

Comment: thanks for your reply..you mean to say i can to do it in data source itself..i want the filesize to restrict within 10MB(should not exceed 10 MB file size)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your datasource descriptor:

```
<maxFileSizeExceededMessage>Max file size allowed is 10MB</maxFileSizeExceededMessage>

<fields>
    <field name="fieldName" type="binary" maxFileSize="10485760"></field>
</fields>
```

That should impose the file size restriction you want, without additional api calls.

Note that you can even provide your own custom validation message, in case the user tries to upload a file larger than what you define.

Comment: thanks for your response..can you please give me one sample example how to do this in smartgwt..i didn't find any maxFileSize api in smartgwt uploaditem..

Comment: The example above is a real SmartGWT descriptor (the xml type). You can have Java datasource descriptors as well. In that case, you will need to use the `maxFileSize` [member](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee-release/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/serverds/DataSourceField.html#maxFileSize) of your `DataSourceField`. By the way, note that you don't need to explicitly define an UploadItem when you define your field as `binary` in your descriptor. The UploadItem will be created for you for fields of this type.